# Azure function: How to trigger PS script on file addition to blob container to invoke R script processing

Tags: r, powershell, azure, azure-functions

I am looking to create a Azure Function that picks up the file from the Blob storage and send it to a R script.

I followed [this](https://github.com/thdeltei/azure-function-r) to enable R script by adding the Site extensions, which finally workes after few initial hiccups.

Now the issue I have is:

**1.** how to trigger the function when a new file is uploaded to the blob store as this uses the Powershell approach.

**`cd D:\home\site\wwwroot\MyFunctionName
D:\home\R-3.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe script.r 2>&1`**

**2.** How can I access Azure blob file from R script for processing.

does anyone one have simple example that they can share. say just open the file in R and print totals lines in the file.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Azure function hasn't supported blob trigger for Powershell yet, you may consider using ***BlobTrigger - C#*** instead. A C# function that will be run whenever a blob is added to a specified container, and then you can save this blob file to local, then call R script to open and read the file.

Here's a C# function example for your reference.

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, string ext, TraceWriter log)
{
    string basePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%home%\site\wwwroot\BlobTriggerCSharp1");

    // save to current dir
    string filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.{ext}");
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        myBlob.CopyTo(fs);
    }

    // run R script
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process {
        StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = "D:/home/R-3.3.3/bin/x64/Rscript.exe",
            Arguments = basePath + "/script.r " + filePath,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    }; 
    process.Start();
    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    log.Info(output);
}
```

***function.json***

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "mycontainer/{name}.{ext}",
      "connection": "mystorage_STORAGE"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

If your blob file is a TXT file you can read it with `read.table()` in R.

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
df = read.table(args[1], header=TRUE)
print(df)
```